# Cannot run anything from mysql-utilities: "No module named mysql.utilities.common.tools"

Tags: python, mysql

RedHat 6.5. Installed via RPM repos the mysql-utilities 1.3.6 and mysql-connector 1.1.6 packages. `mysqlrplcheck` could be executed (though I never found out if it actually worked). Then I realized that version of the suite is missing what I really need, which is `mysqlrplsync`. So I downloaded and installed *1.5.4* directly from Oracle. Found out `mysql-connector` 1.1 was too old and thus upgraded to 2.1.2 of that suite.

Now if I run *any* of the suites programs, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mysqlrplcheck", line 24, in <module>
    from mysql.utilities.common.tools import check_python_version
ImportError: No module named mysql.utilities.common.tools
```

I think there should be a mysql.py/mysql.pyc in the `<pythonlibpath>/` directory, but there is none. So is this a silly packaging error on Oracle's part?

Note: Not a duplicate of [19247867](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247867/mysqlfailover-no-module-named-mysql-utilities-common-tools) which wasn't really answered anyway. Different environment, (significantly) different versions of the software.

Not a duplicate of [24267017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267017/importerror-no-module-named-connector-conversion) nor its referral because the connector is definitely installed. (Though that might be the problem... see my comment)

UPDATE: Possibly fixed in mysql-utilities 2.1.3. See last comment at bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77819

Comment: OK, the problem seems to be the 2.1 version of mysql-connector-python. When I rollback to the original 1.3 version of mysqlcheck and 1.1 of mysql-connector, it works fine. If I then update only the connector, things break.

Comment: The 1.3 version of -connector (as packaged) contains `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/__init__.py` whereas the 2.x version does not. How do I fix this? Where do I complain?

Comment: The 2.0 version of the mysql-connector works fine.

Comment: Opened bug report with Oracle: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77819

Answer (score 6):

For anyone getting this error on Ubuntu,  installing the .deb from oracle or using apt-get  did not work for me, what did work was:

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-utilities-1.5.6.tar.gz
tar -xvf mysql-utilities-1.5.6.tar.gz
cd mysql-utilities-1.5.6

sudo python2.7 setup.py install
```